# Append negative integer into a list Python

Tags: python

I have already seen [this](http://traceback.format_exc()) issue but it seems not fit for my specific use case.

I have a file called whitelist where I save a number that indicates a type of device and the ID of such devices. The format is something like `37423 = -212, -210, 276` where, in this case, `37423` is the number of the device type and `-212, -210, 276` are the IDs.

Now, I have a code that scans this type of file and adds into a list the IDs:

```
if not(manufacturedid in whitelist):
    whitelist[manufacturedid] = list()
for d in deviceid:
    tmp_d = re.sub(r'\W+', '', d)
    if not (tmp_d in whitelist[manufacturedid]):
        whitelist[manufacturedid].append(tmp_d)
```

where `manufacturedid` is `37423` and `tmp_d` are `-212, -210, 276`

My issue is that when it `.append(tmp_d)` is a negative number, it converts into a positive one and I can't understand why as the `tmp_d` in the `if not` statement should be negative as well.

EDIT: I think the issue is in the `for d` loop as `d` results always positive

Comment: Your call to `re.sub` replaces the `-` in the device id, what's it's purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did

```
tmp_d = re.sub(r'\W+', '', d)
```

as you are dealing with ASCII text we can say `\W` is simply `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, thus it was also match and remove `-`, for example

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\W+', '', '-212'))
```

output

```
212
```

Read python [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) built-in module docs, if you want to know more about `\W`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not append but `re.sub(r'\W+', '', d)` that makes `tmp_d` positive.
Debugging helps with such issues. If the output is not what you expect. Check the input first.